# How to solve this kind of problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, generating-functions

I've just found the following problem:

> $\quad\quad$ $\quad\quad$ $\quad\,$ [image]

And I believe that it could be done with something in combinatorics, my feeling is that generating functions would work for this, although I don't know precisely how. I just happened to think also that linear algebra could be used, but still not sure how. I'm trying to make a system of equations on Mathematica and make it find solutions.

Comment: What kind of numbers are you supposed to put in the blank spaces? Naturals, integers, rationals, reals... And how are the calculation done? I mean from left to right (up to down) or the operations have priority?

Comment: The number in the bottom right corner has to be $1,-1,11$ or $-11$

Comment: What priority of operations is used?  Knowing that may help you narrow down the possibilities.  E.g. in the last column if the numbers are integers and the last operation performed is to multiply, then since 11 is prime, the last entry must divide 11.

Comment: @brick Anything, I guess. I'm not sure if the operations have prority. I just found this randomly on the internet, there were no instructions.

Comment: I solved it using integers, I think it becomes harder if we can only use naturals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The spaces in red can be filled arbitrarily and it is still possible, I recommend you fill them with zeros.(I assume we use PEMDAS).

[image]

At the end I ended up having to use some of the red spots to fix stuff, the top left corner was really usefull because the 332 becomes a zero for that row.